# JQuery Validation and Bootstrap 3 for same form-group

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a question regaring "has-error" class and the complex object.

Basically for single simple type it works pretty well but for a complex object it doesnt.

I have following code:

My validation:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationErrorFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string error)
{
    if (HasError(htmlHelper, ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData), ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)))
        return new MvcHtmlString(error);
    else
        return null;
}


private static bool HasError(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata modelMetadata, string expression)
{
    string modelName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(expression);
    FormContext formContext = htmlHelper.ViewContext.FormContext;
    if (formContext == null)
        return false;

    if (!htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.ContainsKey(modelName))
        return false;

    ModelState modelState = htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState[modelName];
    if (modelState == null)
        return false;

    ModelErrorCollection modelErrors = modelState.Errors;
    if (modelErrors == null)
        return false;

    return (modelErrors.Count > 0);
}
```

Javascript

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
    }
});
```

Here is my editortemplate:

```
@model DatingWebsite.Models.UserDate

<div class="form-group@(Html.ValidationErrorFor(m=>m, " has-error"))">
    @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Birthdate, new {@class="col-sm-2 control-label"})
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Day, Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString() }), Base.Day, new {@class="form-control" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.Month, Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i)}), Base.Month, new {@class="form-control" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.Year,  Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-80).Year, 80-18).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString()}), Base.Year, new {@class="form-control" })

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Day, null, new { @class = "help-block" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Month, null, new { @class = "help-block" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Year, null, new { @class = "help-block" })
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the model:

```
[Required]
public int Day { get; set; }
[Required]
public int Month { get; set; }
[Required]
public int Year { get; set; }
```

Now as you can see for the validation i do (m=>m) so i pass the whole object.

1) If i dont fill anything and i submit, i get all of them red, so the style is applied, and i get all error messages in red.

[image]

2) I change the first dropdown list to a value, then the color disappears, and it is not red anymore, although i still see the other 2 error messages ...

[image]

3) if i submit again like this then it will not become red again.

Note: the pictures i added are not with drop down lists, but textboxes because it has the same problem.

Anyone has an idea what is wrong with code?

Update

I've noticed that when I add value to one textbox, then the javascript calls unheighlight function and removes the has-error class, and highlight function is not called for the other 2 textboxes.

Comment: Hmm strange, no one has any kind of experience with this? :(

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and found a solution. It's not pretty, but it seems to work.

I've added the class `multi-validation-group` to my `form-group` divs that can contain multiple error messages and then implemented the following custom unhighlight function, which only removes the `has-error` class from the `form-group` div if no error label remains visible in it.

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  errorClass: "has-error",
  highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).closest(".form-group").addClass(errorClass);
  },
  unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    var group = $(element).closest(".form-group");
    var removeClass = true;

    if (group.hasClass("multi-validation-group")) {
      removeClass = $(group).find("label.has-error:not(:hidden)").length == 0;
    }

    if (removeClass) {
      group.removeClass(errorClass);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way to accomplish this would be to structure your HTML Bootstrap markup so each input has its own form-group, that way the validation `highlight` and `unhighlight` methods work correctly. The [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) can show you how to construct the proper HTML form layout to accommodate this.